# Stand-alone app with wxWidgets

Tags: c++, dll, codeblocks, wxwidgets

I've got a problem with my app, when it comes to executing it in compiled .exe form. I am new in this and I don't know where the problem is. I already tried to search this problem on Google & this site but nothing what I found helped me.

I am using Code::Blocks IDE with MinGW and wxWidgets 2.8.X installed.

Everything works fine inside IDE, but when I try to run it as exe - already compiled - I get an error like this:

```
The program can not start because the computer is missing wxmsw28u_gcc_custom.dll. 
Try to solve this problem by reinstalling the program.
```

When I copy this .dll file right next to my .exe then it will execute without any errors.

Any clues how to fix it ? I guess it's easy to fix but I really don't know how ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It needs the DLL file to execute. You can either ship that with your app, or compile wxWidgets as a static library, so that it will be shipped in your .exe file (thus making it bigger).

Comment: Yeah, sticking it to my app is one way, but how can i compile it as a static library ? I tried some ways but nothing really worked for me.

Comment: wxWidgets has documentation on the different options for compilation [here](https://wiki.wxwidgets.org/WxWidgets_Build_Configurations).

Comment: I build it now as a static library, but when I try to link it to my project and build it i get lots of another errors, for example:
obj\Release\GUIFrame.o:GUIFrame.cpp - undefined reference to `__gxx_personality_sj0'
obj\Release\GUIFrame.o:GUIFrame.cpp - undefined reference to `_Unwind_SjLj_Register'